# SSRS IIF Expression Returning #Error for False Values but not for True

Tags: reporting-services

I have been stuck on this problem for like three days now. I have a report that takes a parameter and based on the value of the parameter, returns one of three possible datasets. One dataset contains a field that the other datasets do not. I wrote an IIF expression to determine which dataset I am looking at to know whether or not I can use that field. It works great when I am using the dataset containing C_S, but not with any other dataset. I read somewhere that it looks for the true field (C_S) even when the expression evaluates to false and to use a switch instead, which I tried to no avail. I also tried a nested IIF, which did not work either. I also tried altering the datasets to always return that field, but that also did not work. There are no null values in the datasets for the CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION field I am evaluating with this expression. I am very new to SSRS and would greatly appreciate some help!

My current expression:

```
    =IIF(Fields!CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION.Value = "AC", Fields!C_S.Value, 
    Fields!TITLE.Value)
```

I also tried:

```
    =IIF(Fields!CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION.Value <> "AC", Fields!TITLE.Value, 
    Fields!C_S.Value)
```

which still only worked for C_S.

Nested IIF I tried:

```
    =IIF(Fields!CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION.Value = "AC", Fields!C_S.Value, 
    IIF(Fields!CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION.Value = "OS", Fields!TITLE.Value, 
    Fields!TITLE.Value))
```

Switch I tried:

```
    =Switch(Fields!CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION.Value = "AC", Fields!C_S.Value, 
    Fields!CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION.Value = "OS", Fields!TITLE.Value)
```

Only one dataset is available to the report at a time

Comment: are the fields you want to return in different datasets? It sounds like they are. If so you will need to edit your question, show some sample data from each and the desired output. Depending on the relationship between each dataset you might need to lookup the values

Comment: @AlanSchofield, only one dataset is returned by the stored procedure for the report and that is based on a user selected parameter. The CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION field is what I am using to determine whether the dataset containing C_S was returned or one of the other two datasets, but the report only has access to one dataset at a time. I am using either the C_S or TITLE field simply as text output to the user. I hope this helps clarify my situation. Due to the nature of my project, I cannot post real sample data, but I can create something if need be.

Comment: I would suggest checking that the data types returned are always the same and then displaying each of the fields listed above so you can see what's actually being compared in your expression. Failing that, some sample data would be useful showing a couple of different scenarios. The expressions you posted look fine on the face of it so I would guess it related to the data itself.

Comment: I don't think this would be able to work without creating the C_S column with a NULL value for the other datasets in the Stored Proc. Anything in SSRS that checks the C_S field when it doesn't exist will return an error. If you can't update the SP, put the SP results into a temp table and add the column if needed.

Comment: @HannoverFist I must have not committed my stored procedure changes before because I just tried updating the other tables to contain the C_S field again and it worked this time. Thank you!